# Label is found as nil despite being linked in IB

Tags: ios, swift3, option-type, xcode8

Swift3/Xcode 8.1

The following code...

```
class PageContentVC: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{

    var array = [String]()
    var currentIndex = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        array = ["1","2","3","4"]

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        self.setViewControllers([helperFunction(index: currentIndex)], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func helperFunction(index: Int) -> UIViewController{


        let newVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageContent") as! PageContent

        print("currentIndex is: \(currentIndex)")
        print("value at currentIndex is: \(array[currentIndex])")

        newVC.PageContentLabel.text = array[currentIndex]

        return newVC
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{

        if (currentIndex ==  0) || (currentIndex == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }
        currentIndex -= 1
        return helperFunction(index: currentIndex)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{

        if (currentIndex == array.count - 1) || (currentIndex == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }
        currentIndex += 1
        return helperFunction(index: currentIndex) 
    } 
}
```

...crashes the app with an "Unexpectedly found nil whilst unwrapping an optional value" error at the following line:

`newVC.PageContentLabel.text = array[currentIndex]`

'PageContentLabel' is definitely linked via interface builder and when I comment out the offending line, the app runs fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure newVC is not nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label is `nil` because you've instantiated the view controller, but the view hierarchy defined in the storyboard, as configured in IB, isn't built until the corresponding view is presented. You should add a string property in your view controller and have `helperFunction` populate that, not the `IBOutlet`. Then, the `viewDidLoad` of `PageContent` should take that string property and use that to set the `text` of the `UILabel`. Bottom line, don't try to use the outlets until `viewDidLoad` has been called.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Would't it be simpler to use outlets?

```
@IBOutlet weak var PageContentLabel: UILabel!
```

ctrl drag from the UILabel in storyboard and to your PageContentVC file right under the class and make an outlet and name it whatever you want.

Comment: The problem is that he's trying to reach into another view controller and set a label, which is bad design. See Rob's answer.